# Angular Highchart data is not updating on toggle button

Tags: highcharts, angular-highcharts

Data is not updating on toggle button, while updated data is provided to chart. Chart is not reflecting updated data. Please help me how to fix?

Note: I am using Angular Highcharts official wrapper.
"highcharts-angular": "^2.10.0"

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you add in some code here to understand what are you doing?

Comment: @Manit here you can find code, I reproduce bug in codesandbox.

[https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-fermi-ceiix?file=/src/app/app.module.ts]

Comment: I am afraid that the demo which you have provided doesn't work.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel, Every things seems fine I am so confused why it is not working.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel now demo is working. Please help me with my problem as soon as possible.

Comment: @MueedUllah are you sure? The link that is shared above shows the error, not the chart component.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-fermi-ceiix?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @MueedUllah excellent, now your demo is working and what is more, I can see that the toggle button works properly also. Do you have any other issues that you need to help with?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel I am wondering my code is working properly as I need in codesandbox but not working at my end.

Comment: @MueedUllah I am afraid that I am not able to help in this case, because I don't have an access to your app - that's why we asked for the online reproduction. I am pretty sure that you are able to find where the problem is by closely comparing the code from the demo and in your app.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Yes, I am trying hard to find the problem at my end.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel, I have added screenshots of my data and graph as you can see in the screenshots data is correct but graph is not plotting data as in the screenshot. Also I found that error in console.

[https://www.highcharts.com/errors/15/]

Comment: Try to sort you data array (x values) in the ascending order before adding it to the chart.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Yayy, Issue resolved by remove type: "category" from xAxis configuration.